# Hibernate - Database stops responding after a few queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm using Hibernate 5.2.6 along with a Tomcat server in order to make queriesto a MySQL database. It works fines until the application reaches 7 calls to the database.

No matter what the calls are (getAll(), find(), update(), customs methods), the database stops responding after 7 calls. It is not a matter of time, because I can let the application run for several minutes without crashing. But as soon as the 7 calls are made, it hangs. There is no error message.

Here is the query 8 that shows in the server console with no response from the database :

[image]

Here are two services that I call (the first was generated by Hibernate ; I created the second one) :

```
@Override
public List<E> getAll() {
if (!currentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
    currentSession().beginTransaction();
}
List<E> ret = currentSession().createCriteria(daoType).list();
return ret;
}

@Override
public List<Subcategory> findByCategory(Category cat) {

if (!currentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
    currentSession().beginTransaction();
}

Query query = currentSession().createQuery("from Subcategory where category = :category");
query.setParameter("category", cat);
List<Subcategory> listSub = query.list();
return listSub;
}
```

Is there a probleme with the services I call ? Or is this a server configuration issue ?

Thanks for helping me !

**EDIT**

Here is an example of how I changed my methods :

```
@Override
public Audit findAuditById(int id) {

    if (!currentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
        currentSession().beginTransaction();
    }

    Query query = currentSession().createQuery("from Audit where idAudit = :id");
    query.setParameter("id", id);

    Audit audit = (Audit) query.uniqueResult();

    Hibernate.initialize(audit);
    currentSession().getTransaction().commit(); 
    currentSession().close();

    return audit;
}
```

And here is the "no session" error I get :

```
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Marshalling Error: could not initialize proxy - no Session
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Marshalling Error: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.safran.engineering.esurvey.ws.impl.EsurveyWebServiceImplServiceSoapBindingStub.getAuditById(EsurveyWebServiceImplServiceSoapBindingStub.java:411)
    at model.impl.ImpGUI_Home.getAuditById(ImpGUI_Home.java:160)
    at model.Abstract_Home.lambda$1(Abstract_Home.java:77)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Should not you  commit() the transaction somewhere ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsyDW.png

Comment: Do you have a connection pool size of 6?

Comment: @user993553 I just added a commit() before the return statement of my services, I got this error : "Marshalling Error: could not initialize proxy - no Session". Is this the place I should be putting the commit() ?

Comment: @Firilou, As mentioned in the first comment, you need to commit the transaction which has been started in the very start of the methods. Whenever you encounter this kind of problem, db does not respond, no exception, etc., most of the time, the table you're querying is locked by some previous query. In such scenario, you won't be able to fire any query on the Locked table even using query browser.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is retrieving a list then you don't need to start a transaction. You only need transactions if you are deleting, updating or inserting records. In general if you are starting a transaction then (mostly) in the same block of code I'd expect to see a commit or a rollback. I'm not sure how or if MySQL supports nested transactions, so that might be a cause of problems.

Alternatively, if MySQL itself is stopping (which you will know if you can't then connect to it from MySQL Workbench and you'll know because it will be more than just your application that will need to be restarted), then take a look at the log files mysql generates as that might give a clue as to why. That's only likely to be a problem if there is a hardware error, but that's just a feeling.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian said, you need not have transactions for select queries.

If you still want to have them, then you need to commit the transaction and close the session. Then call initialize method to avoid lazy loading issues.

```
    @Override
public List<E> getAll() {
    if (!currentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
        currentSession().beginTransaction();
    }
    List<E> ret = currentSession().createCriteria(daoType).list();
    // Call initiliaze to avoid lazy loading exception.
    Hibernate.initialze(ret);
    // You need to commit the transaction & close the session.
    currentSession().getTransaction().commit(); 
    currentSession().close();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I tried changing my methods using your code, but I still get this error : "Marshalling Error: could not initialize proxy - no Session". Plus, when I delete the transaction part (since I don't need it), it says that I can't create a query without a transaction. Any hint ?

Comment: Edit your question and post complete stacktrace for the proxy - no session, issue.